# How can I set the artwork for an M4A file using AVFoundation on iOS?

Tags: ios, image, metadata, avfoundation, m4a

I have an M4A file and I'd like to set its artwork from a `UIImage`. Here's what I've got so far:

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:outputURL];
AVMutableMetadataItem* item = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
item.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork;
item.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
item.value = imageData;
NSArray* metadata = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
exportSession.metadata = metadata;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // ...
}];
```

I've tried a few different things, including:

- `AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon`
- JPEG images
- Exporting to a different URL than the one of the existing file
- Metadata item value as a dictionary with a `data` key instead of just the data

I'm trying to extrapolate based on examples of how to get metadata from a file, because I can't find any documentation about this anywhere. Any help is appreciated.